# How to add an extra row to each object returned from a Laravel database call?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to PHP and new to Laravel. I'm taking over an old project.

We had this code and it was working fine:

```
public function getList(Request $request)
{
    $apiFormat = array();
    try
    {
        $perPage = Input::get('page_size', 10);
        $filters = $request->input();
        $postRepo = new PostRepo();
        $user = $_SESSION["user"];
        $listPost = $postRepo->getlist($user->id, $perPage, 0);
        $apiFormat['status'] =\Config::get('constants.api.STATUS_OK');
        $apiFormat['message'] = \Config::get('constants.api.SUCCESS');
        $apiFormat['data'] = $listPost;
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        $apiFormat['status'] = 
            \Config::get('constants.api.STATUS_ERROR');
        $apiFormat['message'] = $ex->getMessage();
    }
    return response()->json($apiFormat);
}
```

This returned 10 items that would show up on our newsfeed.

This line:

```
$listPost = $postRepo->getlist($user->id, $perPage, 0);
```

Did a database call like this:

```
$sqlCheckHasLike = "SELECT count(*) > 0 FROM `likes` WHERE `post_id` = `posts`.`id` and `user_id` = '".$user_id."'";

$query = DB::table('posts')
->select('posts.*',DB::raw("($sqlCheckHasLike) as is_like"), 'users.full_name', 'users.avatar', DB::raw("post_categories.name as post_categories_name"))
->leftJoin('users', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
->leftJoin('post_categories', 'post_categories.id', '=', 'posts.post_category_id')
->where('posts.status',$post_status)
->where('users.status', 1)
->where(function ($query) use ($user_id, $list_user) {
  $query->whereIn('user_id', $list_user)
    ->orwhere('user_id', $user_id);
})
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate($pageSize);
return $query;
```

However, we've just added comments to each item in the newsfeed. That code is handled elsewhere, but here I want to find, given a post.id, how many comments belong to it? This needs to be included in the response.

Replacing the first method, I tried this:

```
 try {
     $perPage = Input::get('page_size', 10);
     $filters = $request->input();
     $postRepo = new PostRepo();
     $user = $_SESSION["user"];
     $listPost = $postRepo->getlist($user->id, $perPage, 0);
     $array_of_rows = [];
     foreach ($listPost as $lp) {
         $row_as_array = (array) $lp;
         $post_id = $lp->id;
         $query = "select count(id) as how_many from comments where 
            post_id = '". $post_id  ."'";
         $result_array = DB::select($query);
         $result_obj = $result_array[0];
         $how_many = $result_obj->how_many;
         $row_as_array['how_many_comments'] = $how_many;      
         $array_of_rows[] = $row_as_array; 
    }
    $merged_list_post = (object) $array_of_rows; 
    file_put_contents("/var/log/api_debugging", "\ncomment count:\n", 
        FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX); 
    file_put_contents("/var/log/api_debugging", 
        print_r($merged_list_post, true), FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX); 

    $apiFormat['status'] = \Config::get('constants.api.STATUS_OK');
    $apiFormat['message'] = \Config::get('constants.api.SUCCESS');
    $apiFormat['data'] = $merged_list_post;

  } catch (\Exception $ex) {
      $apiFormat['status']=\Config::get('constants.api.STATUS_ERROR');
      $apiFormat['message'] = $ex->getMessage();
  }
```

This does not throw an error (there are no Exceptions) but it changed the returned data, such that the apps which consume this feed no longer get what they need.

Is there an official approach in Laravel that makes it easy to do several database queries, and combine that data at a per inner object level? I'd like to avoid returning an object that is of a different type than the one in the original example.

Comment: You could really benefit from using Eloquent and relationships here, you could reduce this code to a few lines.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: @JeffGallant, is this legacy project initially not coded in Laravel and just recently moved? before we could suggest an `eloquent` answer, perhaps you need to post your table schema a bit, and you may challange yourself to [write an `eloquent` `model`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#defining-models).

Comment: @BagusTesa -- this project isn't "legacy". It was written in late 2017. It's less than 6 months old. It was written in Laravel. I took over in February.

Answer (score 0):

You could just modify the original query (I've just included the first few lines here) to `JOIN` the `comments` table and get the count:

```
$query = DB::table('posts')
->select('posts.*',DB::raw("($sqlCheckHasLike) as is_like"), 'users.full_name', 'users.avatar', DB::raw("post_categories.name as post_categories_name"), DB::raw("count(comments.id) as how_many"))
->leftJoin('users', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
->leftJoin('post_categories', 'post_categories.id', '=', 'posts.post_category_id')
->leftJoin('comments', 'comments.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
```

You will also need to add a `groupBy` clause:

```
->groupBy('posts.id')
```

prior to the `orderBy`.

Comment: Hi Jeff, did this help?

Comment: That doesn't work, it returns the number of comments that exist in the comments table, but it doesn't give me the number of comments per post.

Comment: Hi Jeff, sorry, didn't notice there wasn't a `groupBy` clause in your original post. If you add the one in my edit, that will give you the number of comments per post.